# How do I optimise my code for big test case

Tags: python, performance, optimization

So what I am doing is to find if it is possible to find a for which the sum of numbers on the right side and left side are equal 
for eg: 1 2 1 should return YES because sum of elements on either side of 2 are 1
but 1 1 2 1 should return false.
My code works except for the following huge test case
https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/2490/input03.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1504259349&Signature=gdIq12uki3Nq8YeXKDAKdqJG9k0%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Input line is as followsThe first line contains , the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line contains , the number of elements in the array . The second line for each test case contains  space-separated integers, denoting the array .

Logic of my program:if sum of first i elements =total-(sum of first i elements)-ith element

Code:

## !/bin/python

import sys

def solve(a,n):

t=sum(a)

```
if len(a)==1:

    return "YES"

for i in range(1,n-1):

  sum1=0

  sum2=0

  j=i

  for j in range(0,i):

    sum1+=a[j]


  # for j in range(i+1,n):

  #   sum2+=a[j]
  # print str(sum1) + " " + str(sum2)

  if sum1==(sum(a)-a[i])-sum1:

    print str(sum1) + " " + str(sum2)

    return "YES"

return "NO"
```

T = int(raw_input().strip())
for a0 in xrange(T):

```
n = int(raw_input().strip())

a = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))

print "Iteration " + str(a0)

result = solve(a,n)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(a) # if possible store the value of this outside loop as it is of O(n) complexity
```

---

```
for j in range(0,i): # keep a variable to calculate sum till i instead of looping over.

    sum1+=a[j]
```

---

```
def abc():
    a=[2]
    if len(a)==1:
        return ("yes",0)
    tsum=sum(a) #total sum
    psum=0
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        psum=psum+a[i-1]     # temp var
        #print psum;
        if psum==tsum-a[i]-psum:
            return ("yes",i)
    return "no"
print abc()
```

Comment: did that but it does not pass that test case because of time out.

Comment: I did not understand when you said # keep a variable to calculate sum till i instead of looping over.

Comment: Yes it did work...thanks.So that inner loop was causing all that problem...silly me.

Comment: Sorry but I donot know how to edit my answer as a code.Thing is I edited my code with a different logic to copy that first portion of array to another array and find the sum.But I still have timeout errors.How do I fix this.`def abc(a):
    total=sum(a)
    if len(a)==1:
        return ("yes",0)
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        a1=a[0:i]
        sum1=sum(a1)
        if sum1==(total-sum1)-a[i]:
            return "YES"
     return "NO"`

Comment: Please look into this

Comment: `a1=a[0:i]` and `sum1=sum(a1)` will not be O(1) but O(n) . abc will be O(n^2) not O(n). variable can be used to store value .recalculation in every loop is not necessary here.

Comment: how else would e\it be possible.Recalculation seems the only option to me.

Comment: An edit was done earlier in the answer for a possible algorithm. store the sum in a var as the list is traversed. See code.